# Hydrator and Naming Strategy in Silex or Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, silex, strategy-pattern, hydration

I'm looking for some **Hydrator** or **Factory Hydrator** with configure many different strategy mapping fields for **Silex** or **Symfony**.

I have many dimension array with different structure and I want to set some rule or mapping and create one the same object my class (similar structure like Entity model).

I find something like that in **Zend**: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.namingstrategy.mapnamingstrategy.html.

Maybe is some way to create this in **Silex** or **Symfony** ?

Comment: so why don't you use zend framework ? :D

Comment: I don't  want put in Silex project big lib form ZEND